# Difference between tcpdump and port mirroring? (Layer 3 switch)

Tags: networking, routing, switch, mirroring, switching

When you can use TCPdump on an interface of a layer 3 switch in order to analyze the packets, why do we need to use the mirroring feature and make duplicate copies of the packets on that interface in order to have it sent over to either the CPU or another switch analyzer?
How is it different from using tcpdump?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to capture traffic between two endpoint hosts and general multicast/broadcast traffic, you can run `tcpdump` right on one of the hosts.

However, that doesn't always give you a true picture of what's being sent and received "on the wire" because sometimes the NIC hardware or driver or lower layers of the network stack will mess with the transmitted packets after they get sent up to the sniffer app, but before they actually go out on the wire, and they may play similar games on received packets before they get sent to the sniffer app. Various hardware offloads like hardware checksumming, transmit segmentation offload (TSO), and large receive offload (LRO) are famous for this.

So if you want a more accurate view of what really went across the wire, you need to run your sniffer on a separate machine. But any switch, even a cheap unmanaged Layer 2 switch, won't send unicast traffic to ports it's not destined for. So your independent sniffer machine can't see the unicast traffic between the target hosts in question. This is where Port Mirroring comes in. You're basically telling your managed switch that you want everything to/from the target port to also go to the mirror port, and you connect your sniffer to the mirror port so it can snoop on all that traffic.

This wasn't necessary back in the days of hubs, because hubs were dumb repeaters that blindly forwarded all traffic to all ports. But hubs went out of favor in the early days of 100Mbit "fast" Ethernet (100BASE-TX), and gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) doesn't allow hubs at all; gigabit Ethernet is always switched.

Edited to add: I just realized I could read your question two different ways. If you're talking about running tcpdump internally on the managed switch, that's usually "good enough" to be an independent view of what really went across the wire, as long as your switch itself isn't part of the test or target traffic in question. For example, if you were debugging a protocol that the switch gets involved in, like Spanning Tree or PTP or port aggregation, then you might not want to trust the switch's internal view of what happened.